Bit Probabilities in Constrained Binary String Addition with Fixed Digits
Problem Description:
We have three binary strings:

b1 of length n
b2 of length n
c of length n+1

These strings are related by binary addition: b1 + b2 = c

Example: If n = 4:
b1 = 1011
b2 = 0110
c  = 10001

Now, we fix two bits in either b1 or b2. Let's say we fix the 1st and 4th bits of b1 to be 1 and 1 respectively.
We want to find:
For each unfixed bit in b1 and b2, what is the probability it will be 1?
To calculate this:

Consider all possible combinations of b1 and b2 that:

Sum to c
Have the two specified bits fixed as we set them


Assume each of these valid combinations is equally likely
For each unfixed bit position, count how often it's 1 across all valid combinations
Divide this count by the total number of valid combinations

We need to do this calculation for every unfixed bit in both b1 and b2.
What I've Tried:

Brute Force Approach: I tried generating all possible combinations of b1 and b2 that sum to c and have the fixed bits set correctly. Then I counted the occurrences of 1s for each bit position. However, this becomes computationally expensive for large n.
def brute_force(n, c, fixed_positions, fixed_values):
    total_valid = 0
    count_ones = [0] * n
    for b1 in range(2**n):
        if all(((b1 >> p) & 1) == v for p, v in zip(fixed_positions, fixed_values)):
            b2 = int(c, 2) - b1
            if 0 <= b2 < 2**n and bin(b1 + b2)[2:].zfill(n+1) == c:
                total_valid += 1
                for i in range(n):
                    count_ones[i] += (b1 >> i) & 1
                    count_ones[i] += (b2 >> i) & 1
    return [count / (2 * total_valid) for count in count_ones]

This works for small n but is too slow for larger values.

Recursive Approach: I attempted a recursive solution, trying to build the strings bit by bit while maintaining the constraints. However, I struggled with handling the carry-over in binary addition efficiently.

Dynamic Programming: I thought about using DP, creating a table where dp[i][j][k] represents the number of valid combinations for the first i bits, with j as the carry, and k as the current bit of c. But I'm not sure how to incorporate the fixed bit constraints into this approach.

Probability Theory: I considered using the fact that the sum of two independent Bernoulli variables is a Binomial variable. However, I'm not sure how to account for the dependence introduced by the fixed bits and the constraint of summing to c.



Question: How can we efficiently calculate these probabilities for all unfixed bits, especially for larger values of n? Is there a more clever approach that I'm missing?

To clarify what you're asking, please include an example of inputs to your brute-force program, showing what you consider to be the correct output (i.e., show what you consider to be the correct answer to "For each unfixed bit in b1 and b2, what is the probability it will be 1?").
